# Git push or pull on server

Tags: git, azure, ssh

I have VM in Microsoft Azure with **Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS**, I was recommended to restart it then update, I did. Before, my git repo worked fine(Pull and push). Right now I cannot do it, when I try I get this:

```
ssh: connect to host hostname.com port 22: Connection timed out fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

And I don't think it's the ssh problem cause I can log into VM using ssh. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I don't understand your question. How is git related to your vm? Where is your git repo? Are you saying you set up a git repo on your vm? Please edit your question to provide more details. But... right now, this doesn't look like a programming question, and it seems to be more suited to ServerFault or SuperUser if it's about general VM issues.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer. It was connecting to the default ssh port 22 which is different from my port.

- **Add remote server**

> git remote add your-desired-name ssh://your_username@***.com:your_app_port/your/git/repo/path

- Then you keep using the git command as usual.

Answer (score -1):

"Connection timed out" means that your client (in this case, the `ssh` program) tried to make a TCP connection to the remote server, but the remote server never responded. Common reasons for this are:

- The remote server is not running.
- The remote server is disconnected from the network.
- Some firewall is blocking your access to the remote server.
- The remote server is up and running, but it's not using the IP address that your client tried to connect to.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I can log into my remote server using ssh, but I can't do anything regarding **git** (push, pull, clone,..). According to your comment it is probably firewall, but I don't understand how it can block ssh for git not ssh at all.